# Get indices from pixels with a certain value in PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, pixel

I'm working in the Python-Console of QGIS and I have an object form the class `QgsRasterLayer`. I want to get the indices of those pixels that have certain pixel value (e.g. I need the indices of all the pixels with a pixel value = 50), but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

This script should work:

```
# lyr = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer() # You don't need this if you already have a QgsRasterLayer
prov = lyr.dataProvider()

extent = prov.extent()
width = prov.xSize()
height = prov.ySize()
block = prov.block(1, extent, width, height)

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        val = block.value(y, x)
        if val == 50:
            print x, y
```

Note that this gives you the indices of the pixels, and not their geographic coordinates.

Comment: Thank you a lot ArMoraer!! Instead "xSize" and "ySize" for me only lyr.width() and lyr.height() worked. But I got a problem in the 'block' line. I tried these: block = lyr.dataProvider().block(1, lyr.extent(), lyr.width(), lyr.height())--> But I get this error: "AttributeError: 'QgsRasterDataProvider' object has no attribute 'block'". Infortunately I'm working with the python console in a very old version of QGIS (Lisboa-1.8) because I'm at work and for specific reasons they don't want to move to a recent QGIS version. Can that be the reason why 'block' does not work for me?

Comment: From [QGIS 1.8 API doc](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsRasterDataProvider.html), it seems that you can use `readBlock()` instead. I can't really test it though, so I hope it will work...

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same error with `readBlock()`. I finally managed to get the indices by creating a numpy array from the raster and then using the function `np.where(raster==50)`. But thank you a lot @ArMoraer, a block seems a pretty straightforward solution, unfortunately not in the version I'm using